# setup mssql database pool connection with the node-mssql module

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I want to use a mssql database for my project. I took the node-mssql module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) and for the database management I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

When executing some queries I don't want to connect to the database multiple times so I want to create a pool to have a permanent connection to the database.

My database manager module:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const db = require('../config/database.js');
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(db).connect();
```

My database configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER || 'sa',
    password: process.env.DB_PASS || '-- myPassword --',
    server: process.env.DB_SERVER || 'localhost',
    database: process.env.DB || 'local_demo_cobra',
};
```

MSSQL Studio I changed the authentication mode to **SQL Server Authentication**

[image]

and here you can see the database managed by the server

[image]

When trying to run the code I get the error

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not
>   connect (sequence)

The database is running on my own system so using `localhost` should be fine. I also tried to change the server configuration to

```
server: process.env.DB_SERVER || 'localhost\\AP-MHERMSEN',
```

but this throws the same error

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost\AP-MHERMSEN

What is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

understand that you trying to connect to newly installed MSSQL locally.
May you please check the below:

1. Ensure firewall port 1433 is open and listening.
   How to check > From CMD, type netstat -an
2. Launch SQL Server Configuration Manager,
   Expand SQL Server Network Configuration,
   Right-click Protocols for SQLEXPRESS,
   Right-click TCP/IP (ensure this is enabled),
   Under Tab IP Addresses, scroll down look for IPAll at the bottom,
   Ensure TCP Port is configured to 1433.
3. Ensure SQL Browser service is running.

Let me know if you stuck in any steps.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response. I added Port `1433` to my firewall. I enabled `TCP/IP` via Configuration Manager and the `SQL Browser` is set to automatic. But I can't find the `Tab IP` / `IPALL`

Comment: Please use below link and assign the port.Scroll down the TCP/IP Properties>IP Addresses tab until bottom.            
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/07/24/sql-server-how-to-listen-on-multiple-tcp-ports-in-sql-server/

Comment: Still same? Did you try restart the service before re-try again?